# bash script prints "No such file or directory" when comparing filenames to string

Tags: bash

I am checking to see if a file I am hoping to create conflicts with a file that has the same name.

```
FILEPATH=/root/logs/pData*.csv
COMPPATH=/root/logs/pData*.csv.gz
shopt -s nullglob
thisYear="$(date +"%Y")"
thisMonth="$(date +"%m")"
thisDay="$(date +"%d")"
thisTime="$(date | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | tr : _)"

for file in $FILEPATH
do
    fileYear="$(stat -c %y $file | cut -d'-' -f 1)"
    fileMonth="$(stat -c %y $file | cut -d'-' -f 2)"
    fileDay="$(stat -c %y $file | cut -d'-' -f 3 | cut -d' ' -f 1)"
    fileTime="$(stat -c %y $file | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | cut -d '.' -f 1 | tr : _)"

    if (("$fileYear" < '1990'))
            then
                    fName="pData_"$thisYear"_"$thisMonth"_"$thisDay"_"$thisTime".csv.gz"
            else
                    fName="pData_"$fileYear"_"$fileMonth"_"$fileDay"_"$fileTime".csv.gz"
    fi

    echo $fName

    for file in $COMPPATH
    do
            if ('/root/logs/'$fName == $file)
                    then
                            echo "OOPS"
            fi
    done
done
```

The script works as intended for the most part, printing OOPS when I run into a file of the same name, but for files that don't exist it prints

```
./compress.sh: line 31: /root/logs/pData_2015_09_18_22_25_44.csv.gz: No such file or directory
```

Why is this printed?

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: In addition to the (correct) answer given by Jamie W, consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing everything it finds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string comparison is wrong. Using single parentheses is creating a sub-shell and trying to execute '/root/logs/'$fName

Set your string compare to be:

`if [[ '/root/logs/'$fName = $file ]]`

See: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Comment: Note: you can also do `if [ -a "fileName" ]` to check if a file exists...

Comment: The original suggestion doesn't get rid of the error print, and OOPS never gets printed.

Comment: The ABS is a very poor choice of references -- one could compare it to W3Schools in the JavaScript world among references with high search rankings but very poorly maintained content. Please consider using either the official bash man page, the bash-hackers wiki, or the Wooledge wiki -- all of which are better about staying up-to-date and avoiding bad practices in their examples.

Comment: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression would be the documentation for `[[` on the bash-hackers wiki; [BashFAQ #31](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) compares `test`, `[`, and `[[` in detail; and the [Tests and Conditionals](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals) BashGuide page comprehensively discusses conditionals in general, going into comparisons with `[[` in detail in section 4.